# Django migrate when model was previously deleted

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

When I do `python manage.py migrate` the desired model doesn't appear in my postgres database. I previously deleted all the tables and then migrated it again and it worked but I don't want that because I have loaded many data in the tables that I will have to load again. How to migrate only a certain model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the migration files in `app/migrations` first and then run `makemigrations` before running `migrate`:

```
python manage.py makemigration
```

Also make sure to delete the corresponding lines in your `django_migrations` table.

Comment: I tried it this way but for whatever reason it didn't work for me. What I did is I deleted the lines of my app in the django_migrations table and at the migration folder at the migration file I deleted the model that I wanted to create. Then make migrations and migrate it worked, thank you for your help.